# Nth power of m for big numbers

Tags: c++, biginteger, pow

There will be two numbers in the input file which are between 1 ≤ n, m < 100.
I should display m to power n. When i use pow(x,y) function it cannot calculate big integers for ex ::: 12 to power 23 normally should show 6624737266949237011120128, but my code displays negative number. Can anyone solve this exercise ?

Comment: show what you've tried so far and others will be more willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not very difficult to do without using external libraries. Store the digits of the number in a vector and multiply digit by digit (like you do in paper).

```
Example:

power(12,23):

Store as start->1->2->end

step 1 result: start->1->4->4->end
step 2 result: start->1->7->2->8->end

and so on...
```

Comment: But how can i use the vector in order to show these digits?

Comment: Iterate through the vector to print them. See the example in [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/) link.

Comment: i read that link but i couldn't understand how to use it in my exercise...can you write the solution of this exercise here plz?

Comment: We at stackoverflow cannot write codes for you. Try to understand the problem from the answer and by the given link. Also try searching the net. If you feel you have a different problem, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your base in a `long double` before calling pow :

```
long double base = 12;
long double result = pow(base, 23);
```

It is not required [since C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) though, you can get a good approximation like this :

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << pow(99, 99) << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

`369729637649726802192985226395427290145296428445515959701359650120802601667133273280053721002700400354392780458116125965728631706472588849812738072765460822138161108630185181415759762204338929270784`

But it is an **approximation**, for instance `Python2` code `print 99 ** 99` outputs this :

`369729637649726772657187905628805440595668764281741102430259972423552570455277523421410650010128232727940978889548326540119429996769494359451621570193644014418071060667659301384999779999159200499899`

To get an exact result in C++, you should look at some [BigInt libraries](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Comment: C++ does not handle infinite numbers by default, you should look at some [BigInt library](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your source code?
Use double is enough to store the result
Below is my test code for you reference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double result = pow (12, 23);
    cout.precision (26);
    cout << "Result: " << result << endl;
}
```

Comment: Execution Result: 6624737266949237011120128

Comment: Or try powl function call: long double powl(long double x, long double y);

Comment: but it still gives wrong answer when i try to find for ex 99 to power 99

Comment: 99^99, I got the answer is 3.6972963764972680219298523e+197, isn't it correct?

Comment: Google show the same result, [link](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=99%5E99&oq=99%5E99&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3778j0j7&client=ubuntu-browser&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=94&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: No, it is not correct, either `bc` or even `python2` output a different result : `369729637649726772[...]` whereas C++ outputs `369729637649726802[...]`.